# Writing/Reading from a file into struct in a struct

Tags: c, file, struct

Lets say I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct s1 {
    int field1;
    int field2;
    struct s2 otherStruct; 
};
```

Where `s2` is some other struct that I made:

```
typedef struct s2 {
    double field1;
    char unit;
};
```

If I use

```
s1 s;

s.field1 = 1;
s.field2 = 2;
s.otherStruct.field1 = 42;
s.otherStruct.unit = '!';

write(file_descriptor, &s, sizeof(s));
```

And then later:

```
read(file_descriptor, &s, sizeof(s));
```

Will it work? I mean, when I try to write `s` to the file, will it write all the fields of `s` correctly? Also, will it read it all back in correctly?

Comment: @ChikChak why do you think it should not work?

Comment: yes, it will work, provided u read back to same type of machine (same endianness)

Comment: @MichaelWalz I wasn't sure if the `read` and `write` functions can 'backtrack' the structs

Comment: as written, the only way this could "work" *at  all* is if `s1` and `s2` are fixed-length arrays of some type, the likes of which we are left to assume are `struct s1` and `struct s2` given only this question. `read` requires a *pointer* for the second argument; the only way this code can be sensible is if those are fixed arrays. So to answer the question most-directly, barring the conditions just mentioned, no *none* of this "works". Post *real* code, and clarify *exactly* what problem you're trying to solve, not just how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Edited again...

Comment: @ChikChak `read` and `write` do not "backtrack" anything, they just read/write raw bytes.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Look,my question is simple,will it work as good as i expect it to work,or not?

Comment: @ChikChak yes it will work. Why don't you give it a try. Look at the answer below for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, if you compile the code with the same compiler, the same compiler flags, and run it on the same machine, and never change the definition of the structs.  Change anything, and it you'll read garbage.

To solve this problem in a more resilient and portable way, consider [Google's protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [Cap'n proto](https://capnproto.org/).